# Exclude entries that appear in another table in SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three SQL tables modeling university courses, their requirements and a student's enrollment as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    id Int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VarChar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE prereq (
    dependent Int,
    requirement Int,
    UNIQUE KEY (`dependent`,`requirement`),
    FOREIGN KEY (dependent) REFERENCES course (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (requirement) REFERENCES course (id)
);

CREATE TABLE enrollment (
    courseId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (courseId) REFERENCES course (id)
);
```

For simplicity's sake, student information has been left out of the schema (in the actual schema, there'd be a `studentId` column in `enrollment` that would be a foreign key to a `student` table, but here it can be ignored).

I need a query to show for a given course the unmet requirements. In other words, the query should show all requirement courses for a given dependent course, but not if that requirement course appears in the enrollment table.

For example, start with the following data:

```
INSERT INTO course (id, name)
VALUES
(1, 'CS 101'),
(2, 'CS 102'),
(3, 'CS 103'),
(4, 'Stats 101'),
(5, 'Stats 102'),
(6, 'LinAl 201'),
(7, 'Machine Learning 201')
;

INSERT INTO prereq (dependent, requirement)
VALUES
(2,1),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(5,4),
(7,3),
(7,5),
(7,6)
;

INSERT INTO enrollment (courseId)
VALUES
(2),
(5)
;
```

A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27dbfa/1) has been created for the above.

Note CS 102 and Stats 102 are the only courses in `enrollment` (which may not make sense in terms of having to meet requirements before enrolling, but the data is only being used for illustrative purposes); neither should ever be returned as an unmet requirement course by the desired query. For CS 103, the query should return only CS 101. For Stats 102, the query should return Stats 101. For Machine Learning 201, the query should return CS 103 and LinAl 201 but not Stats 102. Desired results for all the example classes:

| dependent | required |
| --- | --- |
| CS 102 | CS 101 |
| CS 103 | CS 101 |
| Stats 102 | Stats 101 |
| Machine Learning 201 | CS 103 |
| Machine Learning 201 | LinAl 201 |

My solution was to create two instances of each table, join them all together on requirement, courseId, and course.id, thus creating two independent sets of the three tables all joined together, then select all requirements where the requirement from set 1 is not equal to the enrollment from set 2, thinking this would eliminate any entries that occurred in enrollment, but it still gave me all requirements for the given dependent.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this query? Thanks!

Comment: As you asked for pointers, rather than solutions;  Search the web for `NOT EXISTS ()` or `LEFT JOIN` or possibly `anti-semi-join`.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from one table where not in another](//stackoverflow.com/q/7596073/90527)